# Can a declined H1B application be re-opened?

Tags: immigration, h1-visa

The last year (2019) I received reasons H-1B denial.

Reasons were:

1. LCA not provided
2. No Employer-Employee relationship
3. Services in a specialty occupation

Can this application be reopened with a new employer?

Comment: It would presumably be a fresh application rather than “reopening” anything (which also means providing new copies of all required documents, paying the fee, etc.). Question is whether the earlier application would be prejudicial in any way and what can be done about that. It seems you have at least two other issues to address beside the employer.

Comment: I meant, I will step if reopening an application is possible. Right? I don't have to be selected in lucky draw. I think.

Comment: You have already been selected? It seems my understanding of the process is incorrect so I won't be able to answer that question.